# Redshift returns null if additional columns are added to select

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, join, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I have the following select statement

```
select 

ss.market || ss.speed_group || ss.dprt_time_segment || ss.company|| ss.season, 

f9.market, --( ( (select * from filter_9_criteria) < .5 and f9.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_9_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f8.market, --( ( (select * from filter_8_criteria) < .5 and f8.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_8_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f7.market, --( ( (select * from filter_7_criteria) < .5 and f7.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_7_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f6.market, --( ( (select * from filter_6_criteria) < .5 and f6.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_6_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f5.market, --( ( (select * from filter_5_criteria) < .5 and f5.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_5_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f4.market, --( ( (select * from filter_4_criteria) < .5 and f4.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_4_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f3.market, --( ( (select * from filter_3_criteria) < .5 and f3.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_3_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f2.market, --( ( (select * from filter_2_criteria) < .5 and f2.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_2_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f1.market, --( ( (select * from filter_1_criteria) < .5 and f1.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_1_criteria) >= .5 ) ),
f0.market --,( ( (select * from filter_0_criteria) < .5 and f0.market is not null) or ( (select * from filter_0_criteria) >= .5 ) )

from select_statement ss

left join ** each filter_cte on market, speed_group, dprt_time_segment, company, season **

where ss.market || ss.speed_group || ss.dprt_time_segment || ss.company|| ss.season = ** specific group that I know exists in all filter_cte's **
```

where each filter_#_criteria is

```
select count(*)::float / (select count(*)::float from filter_cte_#) as val from filter_cte_# where year in (2020,2021)
```

and f# is the alias for the corresponding filter_cte_#.

The filter_cte's are used to check that the group at the top of the select (market, speed_group, etc.) exists in each cte where each filter_cte is the same except for what timeframe it looks at.

If I run as shown (right side commented) then I get f9.market, ..., f0.market are all not null as expected, but if I uncomment the right side then all the markets return null and the right side computes only based on `(select * from filter_0_criteria) >= .5 )` (ignoring everything to the left of the `or`).

Is redshift returning null as a result of computational expense? I could understand the right side columns having issues but it leaks into the markets and returns those as null when it shouldn't (since I know that each filter cte matches and if I run with the right side commented all the markets populate).

I've tried not using the filter_#_criteria and selecting from the filter cte's directly (i.e.

```
( ( (select count(*)::float / (select count(*)::float from filter_cte_#) from filter_cte_# where year in (2020,2021) ) < .5 or f#.market is not null) or ( (select count(*)::float / (select count(*)::float from filter_cte_#) from filter_cte_# where year in (2020,2021)) >= .5))
```

but that returned the same issue. I also tried adding parentheses around each individual part of the right side logical statement.

If I uncomment only one of them (e.g. filter_9_criteria) then that market (f9.market) will return null and the rest won't. So I do not understand how the two are linked in this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this type of thing before.  Redshift uses multiple query optimizers and selects which one to use based on an "intelligent" agent looking at the query plan.  I suspect if you run EXPLAIN on both versions (commented and uncommented) you will see that the plans differ at a basic level (not just adding some steps).

While a Redshift bug in one of these optimizers is always a possibility (I've seen it once) it rarely turns out to be the case and I've worked through dozens of instances where clients insists that Redshift has a bug.  The issue is usually ambiguity in the query and the various optimizers making different assumptions.

You've boiled down the query and used some shorthand notation so I'm making my best guess as to what is going on.

You have 10 correlated subqueries that seem to want to return a boolean value.  There are no WHERE clauses shown on these which could be one place that ambiguity crept in.  Correlated subqueries are often the cause in such cases as they tend to be loosely defined as far as the compiler/optimizer is concerned.  Rewriting these as window functions usually inserts rigor that helps the situation.

The CTE code could be important for understanding what is going on.  The optimizer in question could be reusing code between the CTEs and the top select or the correlated subqueries.  One way to understand if this is happening is to save the results of the CTE queries to temp tables and see if that changes the results.

Your JOIN tree and WHERE clause are also opaque to me and I can't see if there are any opportunities for computational reuse to creep in.  But based on my experience I'd focus on the conditional subqueries first.  This query syntax seems to attract ambiguity.

Comment: While not quite a window function replacing the first count(*) with a sum(case when year in (2020,2021) then 1 else 0) seems to have fixed the issue.
And go RPI!

Comment: Good to hear and supports the notion of "stupid optimizer tricks" being at the root of the radical change in behavior.  Your choice now is to either make the query rock-solid or take the win and see if the problem returns down the road.  No right or wrong here just what is best for biz ATM.  And go red! (EE '86)